# Pattern for creating a dictionary of singleton for caching objects

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am trying to create a caching mechanism for objects. Whereas I will create a sort of factory method for creating objects and keep a track of existing objects in a dictionary. So, if an object that is existing in the dictionary, I can simply return that. If the object does not exist, then I can instantiate one, add it to dictionary, and then return it.

Basically, I am creating a dictionary of singletons, so to speak. I can obviously try to stick with creating singletons for every type and then create a dictionary. I was wondering if there is a better way to solve it, because my current plan of dictionary of singletons is not really that efficient.

Comment: Have you ruled out existing caching mechanisms like MemoryCash? If so, why?

Comment: I haven't ruled that out yet. I will try to see what is the way to implement it. Although, I might have to create my own for this purpose. I will still check it for sure.

Comment: why to reinvent the wheel?  Just use a dependancy injection container. you can just register an object in singleton scope and it will do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you an idea that you can use in a wide variety of scenarious adding or removing parts of that class:
You cache some of the objects( that amount might be limited if you need by

> capacity)

It's better to use 2 structures:

> LinledList and Dictionary(retrieve cost O(1))

You keep cached objects in Dictionary and when you need to add one more object you add it to the Dictionary and to the end of the LinkedList and when you get maximum capacity, you delete the first object from LinkedList and the same object from Dictionary to be able to add a new one. When you want to use some object, you simply return it and move it in your LinkedList to the end.

Thus, you keep a track of existing objects in Dictionary without duplicates and you get a "queue" of cached objects in your LinkedList where at the end of LinkedList are the most last used objects. You instantiate objects as you want - for simplicity I did it with Item constructor.

That's not a lightweight solution - for server side it should be simplified avoiding class Item (simplifying node) and using just keys in LinkedList (to keep ordered track of usage).

```
public class Item
{
    public string key;
    public object obj;
    public Item(string k, object o) { k = key; o = obj; }
}
class MyCache
{
    LinkedList<Item> ll = new LinkedList<Item>();
    LinkedListNode<Item> node;
    Dictionary<string, LinkedListNode<Item>> dd = new Dictionary<string, LinkedListNode<Item>>();
    int capacity = 5;     //just for simplicity set capacity for caching

    //here you Add new object
    public void Add(string key, object obj)
    {
        if (cap == 0) return; 
        //check if you already have that object
        if (!dd.TryGetValue(key, out node)) 
        {
            //if capacity exceeded- remove object from beginig of LinkedList
            if (dd.Count >= capacity) 
                RemoveItem();
            Item item = new Item(key, obj);
            LinkedListNode<Item> newNode = new LinkedListNode<Item>(item);
            ll.AddLast(newNode);
            dd.Add(key, newNode);
            return;
        }
        //we move that object to the end of the list
        ll.Remove(node);
        ll.AddLast(node);
        // we may update value if it was changed, like
        node.Value.obj = obj;
    }

    // remove object from LinkedList and Dictionary
    void RemoveItem()
    {
        LinkedListNode<Item> node = ll.First;
        ll.Remove(node);
        dd.Remove(node.Value.key);
    }

    public object Get(string key)
    { 
        //if we have that object, we return it and move to the end of LList           
        if (dd.TryGetValue(key, out node))
        {
            ll.Remove(node);
            ll.AddLast(node);
            return node.Value.obj;
        }
        else return default(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gleb. This actually sounds like a good idea. I can definitely go for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reliable caching solution which I use myself. The main idea is simple.
Taking advantage of an interceptor is an efficient solution. The interceptor will decide to retrieve the data from cache or make a service call.
The solution is made from three different parts. First part is a high encapsulated repository which has at least four main generic methods for injection, fetch and elimination (All or specific). As you can see, the code guarantee that there will be no redundant object in the repository.

**A Simple Repository**

```
 public static class Repository
    {
        private static Dictionary<Type, object> _dictionary;
        static Repository()
        {
           _dictionary=new Dictionary<Type, object>(); 
        }

        public static T ReadRepository<T>()
        {
            var type = typeof (T);
            object item;
            var result = _dictionary.TryGetValue(type, out item);
            if (!result) return default (T);
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T));
        }

        public static void InjectRepository<T>(object value)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            object item;
            var result = _dictionary.TryGetValue(type, out item);
            if(result)return;
            _dictionary.Add(type, value);
        }

    }
```

In the second part you need to create a custom attribute called `[Cache]`. Your Logical methods need to be decorated by this attribute. For instance you have a fetch method which makes a service call to achieve the desired data. Using this attribute, Interceptor will decide to retrieve information from cache or let the method to make it's service call.

**Logical method**

```
[Cache]
public User FetchUser(string userId)
{
  //...
}
```

The prominent point is, You are not allowed to call your logical methods directly. The interceptor is going to do this part. There are different mechanisms and patterns for implementing an interceptor that you can take advantage. Look at code below. Using the delegation concept, I have made my own executor.

```
public delegate User UserDelegation(string userID);
```

**A Simple Interceptor**

```
 public static object Executor(UserDelegation delegation)
 {
  // If it is decorated witch [Cache] attribute, Fetch data from cache
  // Else
  delegation.Invoke(userId);
  //...
 }
```